# How does Jacking Spells with unusual descriptors tied to Class Features work?

Tags: 13th-age

The Bard Talent **Jack of Spells** allows the bard to poach a spell from another spell casting class.

Several Wizard Spells have the descriptor "*Cyclic*"; these spells are usable at will so long as the Escalation Die is Even. If the spell is cast when the Escalation Die is odd, it cannot be used again until the end of combat.

Sorcerer Spells have a similar mechanic with the "*Breath Weapon*" descriptor; Nominally 'Daily' spells, after being used once, they can be used again within the same combat if a successful recharge roll is made.

However, a Bard using Jack of Spells doesn't have the **Breath Weapon** or **Cyclical Spells** class feature of the Sorcerer or Wizard; which leads to the question: If a Bard *Jacks* a 'Cylical' spell, can he reuse it so long as the Escalation Die is Even? Or must he always treat it as a once-per-battle ability? Does he get recharge rolls for a *Jacked* Breath Weapon? What about a Sorcerer picking up 'Cyclical' spells via **Access to Wizardry**? Or a Ranger with **Fey Queen's Enchantments**?

Answer (score 4):

In a more formal system, I would say that the bard would not be able to take advantage of the options provided by those class features.  However, designer intent is stated in the book to be flexible about RAW, leading towards allowing the character to take full advantage of them.  One example of this designer intent is given in the Paladin talent that grants Cleric domains.

The advice and tone, especially in the designer sidebars, also supports not "rules-lawyering" down player/character abilities.

Finally the designers have shown that they will bury some "general purpose" rules under specific subsections where it first comes up, such as tunnelling under monsters, leading to belief that cyclic/breath weapon/etc. are not restricted class features, just keywords that are listed under the classes because that's where they are used.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes, you get all the stuff that comes with the spell. If it's cyclic for a Wizard, it's cyclic for a Bard when spelljacked.